# Minimum detectable effect size for difference in difference estimator

Tags: statistical-power, difference-in-difference

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111452/difference-in-difference-different-group-size/111456#111456) gives a formula for the minimum detectable effect size of the average treatment effect, given that the outcome variable follows a normal distribution, as follows:

$$MDE=\sqrt{\frac{\text{Var}(\widehat{Y})}{n}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{p(1-p)}}(q_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}+q_\lambda)$$

Where $Y$ is the outcome variable, $p$ is the proportion of the sample in the treatment group, $n$ is the sample size, and $q_t$ is the $t$-th quantile of the standard normal distribution.

How is this formula derived?